# Can you change the JSP 404 error message for websphere

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

With websphere if you request a file that isn't available you get an error messsage: "404 file not found" and that is it.

For example, if you request  "/mydogxxxx.html" I get a response 404 file not found.

Pretty basic message.

If I request a jsp that isn't available, "mydogxxx.jsp" I get a 404 error code and stack trace information about my version of websphere and other details.

For security reasons, I need to disable that default jsp 404 error message.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very useful tutorial from the [IBM web site](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/portalwiki.nsf/dx/Customizing_error_pages_in_IBM_WebSphere_Portal_and_IBM_Web_Content_Manager_applications_in_a_multi-site_environment).

Answer (score 0):

See [WebSphere customized error pages](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21393358)

Answer (score 0):

Either add below in web.xml

```
<error-page>        
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error/error404.jsp</location>    
</error-page>
```

Or if your traffic is flowing through HTTP server to the Application server, then modify directive in the webserver's httpd.conf as below and

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/missing.html
```